# Remove one object from Parse.com Array column

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, parse-platform

I am trying to remove one object for an array stored in parse (e.g [user1],[user2],[user3], I was to change to [user1],[user3]). I have a module class which stores the different students on the module, when the user removes the module I want to remove their userID from the array stored in the students parse array.

If that is not possible, how can I retrieve the whole array into a local arraylist, edit it, then put it back?

I have attempted a few things but none has worked so far. this is my current code which deletes the whole row and not just the array:

```
moduleDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final View temp = v;
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Module");
                query.whereEqualTo("moduleCode", getItem(position).getModuleCode());
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> module, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            for (ParseObject delete : module) {
                                delete.remove(currentUser.getObjectId());
                                delete.deleteInBackground();
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(temp.getContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                            Toast.makeText(temp.getContext(), "Error deleting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it which takes the array and stores it locally, changes it, then sends it back to parse. Not the best looking way but it worked!

```
moduleDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                students = new ArrayList<String>();
                final View temp = v;
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Module");
                query.whereEqualTo("moduleCode",getItem(position).getModuleCode());
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                        if (e==null) {
                            if (list.size()>0) {
                                ParseObject s = list.get(0);
                                if (s.getList("students")!=null)
                                {
                                    students = s.getList("students");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    students = null;
                                }
                                if (students!=null) {
                                    if (students.contains(currentUser.getObjectId())) {
                                        students.remove(currentUser.getObjectId());
                                        s.put("students",students);
                                        s.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void done(ParseException arg0) {
                                                Toast.makeText(temp.getContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same issue, solved it a bit differently using removeAll(...). 
In my case I need to delete a ParseObject and then remove from an array inside another ParseObject - lets call it container.

```
    final ParseObject toBeDeleted = ParseObject.createWithoutData(OBJ_TYPE, ITEM_ID);

    final ArrayList<ParseObject> removeArr = new ArrayList<>();
    removeArr.add(toBeDeleted);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(CONTAINER_OBJ);
    query.include(THE_ARRAY);
    query.getInBackground(protestID, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                object.removeAll(THE_ARRAY, removeArr);
                object.saveInBackground();
            } else {
                // something went wrong
            }
        }
    });

    toBeDeleted.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.v(TAG, "deleted " + parseType + " successfully");

            }
        }
    });
```

I hope that will help anyone else who needs it.